# Amazone RDS change Class or copy to new instance

Tags: amazon-rds

I have a RDS instance and I want to change this class to a smaller class, from xlarge to large. I try to do this in console, but it doesn't work.

May be it's easier to create new instance and copy old db to new. But how?

Comment: Amazon RDS will perform the upgrade/downgrade during the next maintenance window.
http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/AdjustingTheMaintenanceWindow.html and 
http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/InstanceSizingGuide.html

Answer (score 2):

You can just "Restore to Point in Time" in the RDS console.  It actually restores to a new instance and you can select the name and instance size.

You can also try to check "Apply Immediately" when modifying the instance you want to resize, which will bypass waiting for the next maintenance window.